# Amd64 - segments and their limit: just 4Gb?

Tags: x86-64, virtual-memory, segment

I am on the amd64 arch, on intel c2d.

I can't understand something simple :

A segment descriptor is a the representation of a process (code segment, data, stack..)

How is it that we are stil limited to 4Gb on the amd64 architecture (that is the limit field in the descriptors).

Should it be 64bit limit and not a 32bit one ?

Comment: From the Intel processor manual, volume 3: "In 64-bit mode, the processor does not perform runtime limit checking on code or data segments. However, the
processor does check descriptor-table limits."

Comment: I missed that one. Thanks Hans. You want to make it an answer ?